# Find sum of one column based on consecutive values of another column in data.table

Tags: r, sum, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a data.table like the following:

```
    dput(DT)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Job = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "h1", "h2", "h3"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 0L), Outsourced = structure(c(1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N","Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Job", "Duration", "Outsourced"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103003178>)
```

which gives

```
         ID      Job     Duration Outsourced
 1:       1       h1        2          N
 2:       1       h2        3          Y
 3:       1       h3        4          Y
 4:       1       f1        4          Y
 5:       1       f2        3          N
 6:       1       f3        2          N
 7:       1       f4        1          N
 8:       1       f5        0          N
 9:       2       h1        2          N
10:       2       h2        3          Y
11:       2       f1        4          Y
12:       2       f2        5          N
13:       2       f3        4          N
14:       2       f4        0          N
```

I want to have the sum of `Duration`, for all jobs that have consecutive "Y" in the Outsourced column. Moreover, if activities belong to different `ID`, they shouldn't be counted as consecutive. One `ID` may have more than one set of consecutive "Y" jobs.

So for this example, the correct answer would be something like

```
        ID V1
1:       1 11
2:       2  7
```

Currently, I use `rle` to find running lengths of "Y" in the outsourced column, and then I try with ifs to do the rest, but I think this can be done more elegantly...
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive? Should there appear at leat two consecutive "Y"s?

Comment: Maybe an ID does not have any consecutive "Y"s. Normally they would have more than one running lengths of "Y"s. But to answer your question, even if there is just one "Y", I want to return its duration.

Comment: Does `DT[, NewCol := sum(Duration), by = list(ID, rleid(Outsourced))][Outsourced == "N", NewCol := NA]` do what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't run it. I get Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rleid". Should I load an extra package?

Comment: `rleid` is from `data.table`. What version of data.table are you running? (run `packageVersion("data.table")`). You probably need to update to the current version

Comment: package version ‘1.9.4’. I updated to 1.9.6 and it worked! Actually, it returns the sum multiple times, but maybe with a "unique" I get what I want... Thanks!

Comment: Try updating with `install.packages("data.table")`. I'm running 1.9.6

Comment: Next time you ask, please specify the expected output so it's easily understandable. You can answer this question yourself with the code you'll use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @docendo discimus suggestion from above, I managed to get what I wanted by adding a "unique" statement:

```
DT[, NewCol := sum(Duration), by = list(ID, rleid(Outsourced))][Outsourced == "N", NewCol := NA]
DT[!is.na(NewCol), unique(NewCol), ID]
```

EDIT: To cover cases that include many sets of Outsourced activities with the same duration, the second statement should be changed to:

```
DT[!is.na(NewCol), sum(rle(NewCol)$values), ID]
```

Comment: You don't need `sumDurations<- ` when using data.table's `:=` assignment by reference operator. I'll edit your answer